# How to kill volume when headphones pulled out

Tags: windows-7, audio

I often use headphones in order to listen to music in work time.  However my chair tends to occasionally have the tendency to yank the headphone cable from my laptop.  Now with my Android phone this wouldn't be a problem as the music will automatically stop playing.  However, Windows does not kill the volume and instead re-routes the sound to my laptop internal speaker system.

Aside from turning off my laptop speakers - is there a small utility available which serves my purpose of killing the volume so my work associates aren't inflicted with erroneous musical tastes?

**Update: GMT 2012/10/15 16:16**

My laptop is a HP Pavilion DV7-1125ea, running Windows 7.  Has an IDT High Definition Audio Driver.  6.10.6276.0  23/03/2010  Checked the website and seems the driver seems than the one I'm using.

Comment: It would be dependent on the drivers for the audio on the laptop, can you post some more information on what model laptop, and if possible, what sound driver it is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your audio driver/software allows you to set discrete volume levels for headphones/headphone jack and in-built speakers, you can set the volume level for the latter as 0 or very low. That way, if the headphones get yanked out, the volume level should drop down to the one set for the speakers.

Comment: That's what I did.  Shame this is a limitation of my audio driver.

Comment: The annoying thing now is the windows volume control groups the headphone and headphone controller together for the default volume controller.  Just have to keep the mixer panel open.  Oh well, think I might go in search of a hardware solution.